# How to export motioned tracked mesh and background video in mp4?

Tags: export, motion-capture

I followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Vm9Jx1pWv8) to mesh on a picture of mine onto a video however the final part about exporting it does not work. Setting up the compositing as he instructs makes it so the masked mesh is exported and the video background is not (ie the "Render Layers" is shown but the "Movie Clip" is not in the exported mp4.) How do I export the background and mask with the mask overlayed on top of the video? [image]

Comment: Some of us will not follow external links to understand a question. Please [edit] your question and show what you have set up on the compositor and explain further what you did and what you expect to get.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering change Blender render to cycles render go to film in the render tab and check transparent. That might create a new issue I'll edit this answer when I solve.